# Expectation value of operators in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, observables

Can the expectation value of an operator be zero?

Comment: Do we ever measure the value of physical quantities to be 0?

Comment: Hint: Which expectation values would you expect for the zero operator?

Comment: @Qmechanic zero?

Comment: @Paradox101  I am not sure whether I understand you, but, of course, the expectation value of $L_x$ and $L_y$ in an eigenstate of $L_z$ is zero. There is a [post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167728/) about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expectation value of an operator is calculated in a specific state. For instance let's consider for simplicity a beam of electrons in a state $|\psi\rangle$ polarized in the direction $x$. The average $\langle \psi|\hat S_x|\psi\rangle = \hbar/2$. However, if the beam is in a state $|\phi\rangle$ polarized in the $z$ direction, $\langle \phi|\hat S_x|\phi\rangle = 0$.

In general, it can be proved that if a particle is in a state $|l,m\rangle$ where $l$ is the orbital quantum number and $m$ the magnetic quantum number i.e. an eigenvalue of $\hat L_i$, where $i =$ $x$, or $y$, or $z$, then

$$\langle l,m|\hat L_j|l,m\rangle = 0, \tag{i}$$

where $\hat L_j$ is one of the two spin-projection operators besides $\hat L_i$, .e. if $i=y$ then $j = z$, or $x$.

**Comment:** another question was posted in this site asking for a proof of eq. $\text {(i)}$, but it was deleted as home-work.